# How to avoid duplicate data into Mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, duplicate-data

order-:

```
order_id(PK)    item     status  order_no
1               pant        0       100
2               shirt       1       200
```

product-:

```
   prod_id(Fk)    id(pk)   price     quantity   order_no  status
   1               1         10          2          100        0
   1               2         20          3          100        0   
   2               3         15          1          200        1
```

These are my two table-: order & product.

what happend is to insert data into product table, my query first check status of order table & if it is 0, it add data into product table.

My program runs through CRON job..so each time it just checks order status & if it is 0,
it again adds same data into product table.

i.e. my product table become like this

```
 prod_id(Fk)    id(pk)   price     quantity   order_no  status
   1               1         10          2          100        0
   1               2         20          3          100        0   
   2               3         15          1          200        1
   1               4         10          2          100        0
   1               5         20          3          100        0
```

which I don't want.  my id column is pk which is auto-incremented...
so **how should I avoid duplicate data into Product table?**

Is there any way we can update or replace the same data??

plz guide me..

Answer (score 3):

Create a `UNIQUE` index on `prod_id` (or whatever columns determine that the record is to be updated rather than inserted), and then use either [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html).

Comment: HI eggyal, I can't create unique index on product table as I am maintaining foreign key prod_id which represent that these products are from that order no. so it may contain same value as an example u can check for order no. 1 there were 2 products.

Comment: @Prat: how do you determine whether you want to insert a new record or update an existing one?  Is it by the `order_no`?  The combination of `order_no` and `prod_id`?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Order status is 0 means data is not moved into oracle...so when order_status become 1 means data move into oracle...but what happened is till the time data move, product data get inserted into product table which I dont want..

Comment: Oracle?  Your question is tagged MySQL.  Anyway, you will need to edit your question to show your query.  It sounds like you simply need to add a `WHERE status = 1` clause somewhere...